# CORS error. How to set response headers

Tags: javascript, integration

[image]

```js
let response = fetch(uploadEndPointURL,{
                        method: 'POST',
                        mode: 'cors',
                        cache: 'no-cache',
                        Body: body,
                        credentials: 'include',
                       
                    
                      headers: {                        
                        
                            'Authorization': "Bearer "+this.accessToken,
                            'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true 
                
                        } ,
                    }) .then(response => response.json())
```

I am new to this and trying to invoke BOX upload API from LWC js file. Now, I am getting

> Access to fetch at `https://******` from origin `https://******` has been blocked by CORS policy.

I searched some links on google and they all are suggesting to set response headers. But my question is how can I set the response headers. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same error and after hours of searching I've ended up with moving the call to apex.

Comment: @Damecek, I can't move my code to apex because from there I am not able to upload large files, as I am getting stuck in governor limits. That's why I tried it from js file using fetch api.